# When I use firebase Cloud function inside unit test some cloud functions do not run

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have 2 firebase cloud functions as you see here

```
exports.delete = functions.firestore.
    document('aaaa/{aaaaId}/bbbb/{bbbbId}')
    .onDelete((snapshot, context) => { 
---
---
}
```

and

```
exports.create= functions.firestore.
    document('/cccc/{cccccChild}/ddddd/{dddddChild}')
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
---
---
}
```

And it works great when I create or delete in the app

But when I execute **locally** inside unit tests with the admin SDK the "create" function doesn't work but the "delete" function does.

Inside the test a use the admin SDK in this way.

```
let result = await admin.firestore().collection('cccc').doc("value").collection("ddddd").add(value2);
```

And the document in the path is created but in the firebase console only show the message 'Function execution took X ms, finished with status: 'OK' ' but doesn't show the console.log() I put in the code but when I execute the line.

```
const userReportDoc = admin.firestore().collection('aaaa').doc('id').collection('bbbb').doc('otherid').
await userReportDoc.delete();
```

The function runs and show all the console.log() in the function without any problem

Any help or advice?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo in the path by having an additional `/` at the start

`/cccc/` vs `aaaa/`

Comment: Sorry i have a typo in the post the truly name of the collection and document are correctly set, the location of the new document is where i expected. I only put aaaa or bbbb because in the company is a kinda jealousy about that kind of information sorry for that

Comment: I would suggest recreating this as a minimal project and deploy it, ensure that it is working as intended as this maybe a bug related to the emulator